# How to stop the recusion of the async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using async task as follows:

```
private first_async first;  // global variable

// In onCreate
first = new first_async();
first.execute(1);

// then on click of the button I want to stop this, but it works after some time like this:
 if (!first.isCancelled()) {
     first.cancel(false);
 }

private class first_async extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    int var;
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
           var = params[0];
           // do some task
         }  
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(void thumb) {
        super.onPostExecute(thumb);
        if (var >= 7) {
        } else {
            first_time_imageURL = new first_time_get_images_URL();
            first_time_imageURL.execute(var+1);
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that cancel on the async task work after some time. If I am uncorrect, please correct me or if some other alternative is there, please mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (!first.isCancelled()) {
 first.cancel(false);
}
```

False should be true here, that will cancel the Asynctask. So:

```
first.cancel(true);
```